# Division alg C to get floating point number

Tags: c, algorithm, division

Hi I got this division alg to display the integer and floating point values.
How can I get MAX_REM? it is supposed to be the size of the buffer where our characters are going to be stored, so the size has to be the # of digits, but I don't know how to get that. thanks!

```
void divisionAlg(unsigned int value)
{

    int MAX_BASE=10;
    const char *charTable = {"0123456789ABCDEF"};  // lookup table for converting remainders
    char rembuf[MAX_REM + 1];   // holds remainder(s) and provision null at the end
    int  index;                 // 
    int  i;                     // loop variable

    unsigned int rem;           // remainder
    unsigned int base;          // we'll be using base 10 
    ssize_t numWritten;         // holds number of bytes written from write() system call

    base = 10;

    // validate base
    if (base < 2 || base > MAX_BASE)
        err_sys("oops, the base is wrong");

    // For some reason, every time this method is called after the initial call, rembuf
    // is magically filled with a bunch of garbage; this just sets everything to null.
    // NOTE: memset() wasn't working either, so I have to use a stupid for-loop
    for (i=0; i<MAX_REM; i++)
        rembuf[i] = '\0';

    rembuf[MAX_REM] = 0;    // set last element to zero
    index = MAX_REM;        // start at the end of rembuf when adding in the remainders

    do
    {
        // calculate remainder and divide valueBuff by the base
        rem = value % base;
        value /= base;

        // convert remainder into ASCII value via lookup table and store in buffer
        index--;
        rembuf[index] = charTable[rem];

    } while (value != 0);

    // display value
    if ((numWritten = write(STDOUT_FILENO, rembuf, MAX_REM + 1)) == -1)
        err_sys("something went wrong with the write");

} // end of divisionAlg()
```

Comment: Ummm, I'm pretty sure `memset` works....

Comment: Also, as an automatic variable, rembuf is allocated on the stack, and by default contains garbage until it's explicitly initialized.

Answer (score 2):

The calculation for figuring out how many digits there are a number takes is:

```
digits = floor(log(number)/log(base))+1;
```

However, in this case, I'd probably just assume the worse case, since it's no more than 32, and calculating it will be "expensive". So just `#define MAX_REM 32`, and then keep track of how many digits you actually put into `rembuf` (you already have `index` for that, so it's no extra cost really). You'll obviously need to calculate the amount of bytes to write out as well, but shouldn't require any special math.

Comment: +1: I was already typing pretty much the same answer when this one showed up. :)

Comment: It's `floor(log(number)/log(base)) + 1`. `base ^ k` needs `k+1` digits.